# Magento Community 1.9.x / OpenMage - Show Correct Remote IP with CloudFlare

Tags: magento-1.9, openmage

When using Cloudflare with Magento Community Open Source 1.9.x (now forked as [OpenMage](https://www.openmage.org/)), one of the first problems many people notice, when using "Proxied" DNS is that the visitor's IP address is "incorrect".

In fact, it's not incorrect, the server is receiving the proxy IP address. Nevertheless, this is not very useful if we're using IP for such things as location etc.

So how do we get the actual visitor IP address?

**TLDR:** *Option 1* is the most appropriate and easiest. *Option 2* is the server-wide solution.

### Option 1: Application Wide

In `app/etc/modules/local.xml.additional` there is the following in `config/global`:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <remote_addr_headers>
            <header1>HTTP_X_REAL_IP</header1>
            <header2>HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR</header2>
        </remote_addr_headers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Copy the `<remote_addr_headers></remote_addr_headers>` and close `app/etc/modules/local.xml.additional`.

The header CloudFlare provides that contains the visitor's actual IP is `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP`. Therefore we need to add the following to the `app/etc/modules/local.xml`.

Open `app/etc/modules/local.xml` and add the `<remote_addr_headers></remote_addr_headers>` code below inside the `<global></global>` section as follows:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <remote_addr_headers>
            <header1>HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP</header1>
        </remote_addr_headers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Kudos to Tall Pall for [this solution](https://tall-paul.co.uk/2012/03/13/magento-show-remote-ip-in-cloudflare-the-right-way/#comment-16280).

### Option 2: Server Wide

This option is preferred with a dedicated server or where sever-wide visitor IP restoration is needed.

Depending on which web server is used, Apache requires either mod_remoteip or mod_cloudflare and or Nginx cloudflare-watch.

Luckily, CloudFlare has [an article on how to do this here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/troubleshooting/restoring-visitor-ips/restoring-original-visitor-ips/).

### Option 3: Tell CloudFlare to Restore Visitor IP

Cloudflare can be configured to pass the visitor's IP address in the `X-Forwarded-For` header. Option 1 and 2 are both better than this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `app/etc/modules/local.xml.additional` there is the following in `config/global`:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <remote_addr_headers>
            <header1>HTTP_X_REAL_IP</header1>
            <header2>HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR</header2>
        </remote_addr_headers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Copy the `<remote_addr_headers></remote_addr_headers>` and close `app/etc/modules/local.xml.additional`.

The header CloudFlare provides that contains the visitor's actual IP is `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP`. Therefore we need to add the following to the `app/etc/modules/local.xml`.

Open `app/etc/modules/local.xml` and add the `<remote_addr_headers></remote_addr_headers>` code below inside the `<global></global>` section as follows:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <remote_addr_headers>
            <header1>HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP</header1>
        </remote_addr_headers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Kudos to Tall Pall.